# Surface at intersection of Clipping Plane and Geometry

Tags: c++, opengl, surface, geometry-shader

I have a geometry with I am displaying using geometry shader in combination with vbo. I also have two clipping planes which are needed to display the portion of the object I want.

Now I want to display a surface to cover the opening(I render a hollow closed surface using geometry shader) in the geometry caused by the clipping planes.

I tried with stencil buffer approach by rendering the geometry twice. But it is awefully slow.

Suggest a way to make it faster.

Comment: Just so I understand, you want to 'cap' off the opening made by the clip planes? For example, cutting a sphere in half, you'd like to have a circle capping the sides where the cut was made?

Comment: @Aeluned .. yes exactly .... but my case .. the geometry is arbitrary ... I know only the planes.